# Add a `StorageMap` to a pallet (metadata) from outside the pallet

Tags: pallet, frame

my problem is the following:

There is a pallet which contains some storage, some extrinsics, and a type in its `Config` implementing `trait CustomPalletHooks` to which it delegates some logic.
Assuming this trait is responsible to collect deposits for some on-chain storage and store them somewhere (i.e, the account paying for it, the currency, and the amount), is it possible for the type implementing the trait to declare a new `StorageMap` that, when included in the metadata, would look like it's part of the pallet? So that, for instance, a client could call `api.query.pallet.storage(key)`?

The reason is that the logic for collecting the deposit should not be tightly coupled with the rest of the pallet logic, but some runtimes might decide to collect some deposit for some on-chain space utilized, and ideally this would live under the same namespace that the pallet lives.

Thanks!